# How do i use node method setAll() and addAll() in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, nodes

I got problem with this method, because i use this method in vbox to get value from the child class. 
The value i got from database, if i use addAll() the data from database always increase, but if i use setAll() the data is no longer increase but just display one last column in my database.
The code it's like `vbox.getChildren().addAll(node);` or `vbox.getChildren().setAll(node);`.
 How i fix this problem?

```
 @FXML
    private void CB(ActionEvent event) {

        String depart = comboBox.getValue();
        String sql = "SELECT b.kota, bb.kota, single.harga FROM single_trip as single \n" +
                    "INNER JOIN departure as depart ON depart.kode_departure = single.kode_departure \n" +
                    "INNER JOIN bandara as b on b.kode_bandara = depart.kode_bandara \n" +
                    "INNER JOIN arrived as arrive on arrive.kode_arrived = single.kode_arrived \n" +
                    "INNER JOIN bandara as bb on bb.kode_bandara = arrive.kode_bandara \n" +
                    "WHERE b.nama_bandara = '"+depart+"'";

        try {
            con.st = con.conn.createStatement();
            con.rs = con.st.executeQuery(sql);
            Node[] nodes = new Node[1];

            while(con.rs.next()){

                for(Node node : nodes){

                    FXMLLoader hb = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ComboBoxloop.fxml"));
                    node = hb.load();
                    String namaDepart = con.rs.getString("b.kota");
                    String namaArrive = con.rs.getString("bb.kota");
                    int harga = con.rs.getInt("single.harga");
                    ComboBoxloopController controller = hb.getController();

                    controller.getValueFromCB(namaDepart, namaArrive, harga);

                    controller.setDepart(namaDepart);
                    controller.setArrive(namaArrive);
                    controller.setHarga(harga);


                    pnlComboBoxloop.getChildren().addAll(node);
//                  or pnlComboBoxloop.getChildren().setAll(node);


                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

**addAll()** method takes your input and add it to the existing values. For a basic list of 3 elements, you will then add your input to the 3 elements (list size = 3 + input.size).

> boolean addAll(E... elements)
>
> A convenient method for var-arg adding of elements.

**setAll()** method erases the existing values and replaces it by the given input (list size = input.size)

> boolean setAll(E... elements)
>
> Clears the ObservableList and add all the elements passed as var-args.

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html